# SQL Server 2005 Perform "RECOVERY" on database restored with "NORECOVERY"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, backup, restore

I have full weekly backups, daily differential backups and hourly transaction log backups.

To restore the database, I restore the full backup, then the last dif backup then all the transaction log backups specifying NORECOVERY on all the restores except the last one.

My question is. If I accidently restore my last transaction log with the NORECOVERY flag set, is there a command I can run to "RECOVER" the database at this point?

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (from SQL2000 help):
RESTORE DATABASE dbname WITH RECOVERY

Comment: I see now that you have found the solution. I posted the answer without refresh the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so the answer is fairly simple. You can simply run the command.

```
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDatabase] WITH RECOVERY
```

It didn't even occur to me that you can run the RESTORE DATABASE command without specifying a backup to restore from.